# How to map value with another DataFrame by using row number?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to replace the `dt_b` at value of column `'Nearest_index'` with value of `dt_a` at column `'target'`.

The value of `dt_b` is index of row. For example, `dt_b` at value equal `0`, it's replaced by value `15` from `dt_a`. Because, value `0` in `dt_b` is the `0` of row index in `dt_a`, so will get `15`.

For example :

```
dt_a  = target
         15
         90
         88
         65

dt_b = Nearest_index
        0
        1
        2
        1
```

Expected result:

```
dt_b = Nearest_target
                    15
                    90
                    88
                    90
```

Now I using manual mapping method

```
index_of_nearest['Nearest_target'] = index_of_nearest['Nearest_target'].map({0: 15, 1: 90,2: 88, 3: 65,4: 16,5: 88,6: 65,7: 90,8: 16,9: 16,10: 90,11: 65,12: 16,13: 16,14: 88})
```

But, sometimes `target` in `dt_a` is changed, so hard coding is not suitable. Please suggest a dynamic mapping method.

Comment: `df_b['Nearest_target'] = df_b['Nearest_target'].map(dt_a.target)`?

Comment: It show 'Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects'

Comment: replace `dt_a.target` with `dt_a.reset_index().target`?

Comment: Thanks, great! Can you explain dt_a.reset_index().target ?

Comment: It forces the index to be `rangeIndex`, which is what you want.

Comment: Oh I see , Thank you very much.